# Why GCC and MSVC std::normal_distribution are different?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++11, gcc, visual-c++

I have a simple code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    minstd_rand0 gen(1);
    uniform_real_distribution<double> dist(0.0, 1.0);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        cout << "1 " << dist(gen) << endl;
    }

    normal_distribution<double> dist2(0.0, 1.0);
    minstd_rand0 gen2(1);
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
        cout << "2 " << dist2(gen2) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which I compile on [gcc](http://cpp.sh/8g7g4) and [msvc](http://rextester.com/SWKQP38269). I get diferent results on std code!(
[image]

So why GCC and MSVC `std::normal_distribution` results are diferent for the same seed and generator, and, most importantly, how to *force* them to be same?

Comment: Fascinating. I would have expected them to have 100% different or 100% identical numbers. The fact they're the same but rearranged blows my mind.

Comment: And `uniform_real_distribution` results  are as expected the same!

Comment: @MooingDuck: The standard algorithm here produces two values each iteration. It looks like they both use the same implementation of the algorithm, but just differ on which of the two values is returned and which is cached.

Comment: They probably both use Knuth's algorithm (vol2, page 122, algo P).  Which repeatedly generates 2 random numbers until the constraints are met.  So you have two good numbers, you return one of them and keep the other for the next call.  You can guess the rest.

Comment: Interestingly enough, clang++ follows MSVC

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's problematic, but the standard unfortunately does not specify in detail what algorithm to use when constructing (many) of the randomly distributed numbers, and there are several valid alternatives, with different benefits.

> 26.6.8.5 Normal distributions [rand.dist.norm]
>   26.6.8.5.1 Class template normal_distribution [rand.dist.norm.normal]
>
> A normal_distribution random number distribution produces random
>   numbers x distributed according to the probability density function
>
> [image]
>
> parameters μ and  are also known as this distribution’s mean and
>   standard deviation .

The most common algorithm for generating normally distributed numbers is *[Box-Muller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box%E2%80%93Muller_transform)*, but even with that algorithm there are options and variations.

The freedom is even explicitly mentioned in the standard:

> 26.6.8 Random number distribution class templates [rand.dist]
>   . . .
>
> 3 The
>   algorithms for producing each of the specified distributions are
>   implementation-defined.

A goto option for this is [boost random](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_random/reference.html)

By the way, as @Hurkyl points out: It seems that the two implementations are actually the same: For example box-muller generates pairs of values, of which one is returned and one is cached. The two implementations differ only in which of the values is returned.

Further, the random number *engines* are completely specified and will give the same sequence between implementations, but care does need to be taken since the different *distributions* can also *consume* different amounts of random data in order to produce their results, which will put the engines out of sync.

Comment: I provide [`minstd_rand0`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/random/minstd_rand0/) generator to it...

Comment: Following Hurkyl points, is it possible to seed MSVC or GCC so that they will provide same results?

Comment: @DuckQueen. No, but you could make a wrapper that swaps the returned pairs of numbers.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike the PRN generators defined by the standard that must produce the same output for the same seed the standard does not keep that mandate for distrobutions.  From [rand.dist.general]/3

> The algorithms for producing each of the specified distributions are implementation-defined.

So In this case even though the distribution has to have a density function in the form of

[image]

How the implementation does that is up to them.

The only way to get a portable distribution would be to write one yourself or use a third party library.